# How to reroute external IP address to localhost?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, loopback

I have a software that I no longer have access to it's source code that is connecting to a server on a certain IP. I want to be able to mimic the same server's functionality and route the IP address to localhost.

However, there is a problem. The software detects Microsoft Loopback Adapters and deletes them upon start-up. It also detects the use of the CMD command `netsh int ip add addr 1 [ip]`, so I can't use that as well.

Is there an alternative way to route the IP to localhost?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the hosts file?

Comment: @DavidPostill He said he wants to route an IP. The hosts file only deals with rerouting or translating a domain. i'm sure the hosts file could translate a domain to an ip, but I really don't think it'd do an ip to an ip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative loopback method?](http://superuser.com/questions/888635/is-there-an-alternative-loopback-method)

Comment: This is the third time you have asked this question ([Is there an alternative loopback method?](http://superuser.com/q/888635), [Alternative loopback method](http://superuser.com/q/888465)). Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot route to localhost, perhaps you can route to another local server and do the spoof there.
Perhaps you can give that server and your machine an extra network address in a /30, with the spoof-server the original IP, and your machine the other IP in that range.